# How to deal with dependencies when cross-compiling

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling, libraries

Having transferred a research project into a startup, I suddenly need to distribute binaries rather than source code + build instructions. I have a C++ codebase built using CMake.

I find myself completely out of my depth here, to the point where I can't seem to find the resources I need to get started. The problem more specifically is how to cross-compile source code in such a way that users can load dependent libraries from wherever they have them installed (also grateful for pros/cons of dynamic/static libraries in these circumstances). Right now, when I build my targets, the binaries automatically link to paths specific to my host environment which of course isn't workable for distributing the binaries. I am looking for:

1. A high level description of how this could be done using CMake,
2. Some pointers to resources that are accessible enough for a complete cross-compiling noob to understand.

**Edit:** I realized I actually have two questions rather than one. One of them was about cross-compiling, and I am satisfied with actually using machines (real or virtual) with different OS to build for each OS, eliminating the need to cross-compile between e.g. Windows and Mac. The other question, which I still don't know how to deal with, is how to build the executable on my machine and distributing it to other machines with the same OS given that the executable uses dynamically linked dependencies which will very likely be installed at different paths, or be of different versions on users' machines. How do I build a binary on my machine, that (possibly with the help of cmake's find_package or something similar) can be linked to the dependencies wherever the user has them installed on their system, without needing to share the source code?

Comment: static libraries definitely make life easier  which platform(s) are you targeting?

Comment: 2 approaches: (1) using the cross-compile tool-chains (if available) - this is hard in my opinion. (2) Use virtual machines each of the supported target platforms and the native tool-chains for each platform.  For both approaches (as Alan said above) using static linking makes the job much simpler.  If you have to use dynamic linking you will probably need an installer to install any missing dependencies.

Comment: You may want to consider cmake's `install` command for specifying a file structure on the system you deploy the binaries and use cpack to generate a package of some kind. Depending on the package type you may need to set additional information. There are some properties you can set specifically for the deployed version of the lib (e.g. `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH`). Also there's the possiblilty of generating cmake config files to use `find_package` to import your binaries as imported targets to a cmake project on the target system.

Comment: I target primarily linux and mac at this point. Windows will also be relevant in the future but not in the short term.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I updated my question above, and would greatly appreciate input on my  clarified question. I probably need to use dynamic libraries for some dependencies. I'll look into Fabian's answer, which seems like it might be what I need. It is currently a bit over my head though, cmake-wise.

Answer (score -1):

form my point of view, use cmake import library project is just fine.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(specific_library)

if(WINDOWS)
    set(imported_lib ${win_lib})
elseif(LINUX)
    set(imported_lib ${linux_lib})
elseif(ANDROID)
    set(imported_lib ${android_lib})
endif(WINDOWS)

add_library(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    STATIC
    IMPORTED
    GLOBAL
)
```

in the main project directory, u can do this

```
add_subdirectory(specific_library)
target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
    specific_library
)
```

Comment: Neither `WINDOWS` nor `LINUX` are standard CMake variables.

Comment: yes, even your `PROJECT_NAME` is not `specific_library` .I try to provide an idea, not an answer.

Comment: But _this is posted as an answer_ and, worse than being merely wrong, it is actively misleading. The code looks _plausible_, but is actually pseudocode at best.